# Magento search customer by first name

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I am creating a magento extension and i need to search the customerbased on their firstname. I know i can do it with the help of sql. But i would like to use the customer model of magento to do the work.

I have used this and it returns an array of all users but instead of all users i want specific users who matches the criteria.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`addAttributeToFilter`](http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/addattributetofilter-conditionals-in-magento.html) method which is used like a simple `WHERE` clause where you can use wildcards, too.

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$query = "John";

$model = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer');

$result = $model->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', array('like' => "%$query%"));

foreach($result as $r) 
{       
        $customer = $model->load($r->getId());
        echo '<b>'.$customer->getFirstname().' '.$customer->getLastname().'</b><br/>';
}
```

Comment: Hey Can you please tell me where to put this file in magneto? and how to search form will be action on this file?

Answer (score 1):

`$c = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('first_name', array('like' => $the_name_you_want_to_find))`

Comment: maybe i dont know what you called your attributes, if its "firstname" or "first_name" if you dont like "like"-queries you can use eq instead. Oh and of course there is no break after getCollection()-